# A maze game for touch-devices

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine, touch-event

Purpose: I want to create a game like [this one](https://cdn-factory.marketjs.com/en/mcdonalds-playable-ad/index.html)

Problem: How to make it so that when dragging an item it does not go beyond the borders of the cell? I can do it like this, but you can easily control it from the keyboard, but somehow I’ll find it difficult to work with dragging. In other words, it is required that dragging an item is only possible along a particular path (as in the example of the game above)

Any thoughts? Any options and solutions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: do you have any code which you have tried? SO is not a coding service. Thanks

Comment: what you need is "some code" - hope that helps

Comment: guys)) i wish to get any advices about libraries , not jokes))

Comment: yes, i have the code, but i see no point to show it, because it's just a draggable object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the example you gave you can do this by placing the walls around the item. Whenever the system detects collision with the walls movement of the item will stop. I have mostly used this functionality with Unity Engine so i am afraid i can't provide you with specific codes.

Check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNV-xEMALr8

I think you will be able to figure this out after watching it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually i solved this problem about 20min ago about your way, but anyway thank you :)))

Comment: Welcome. I was glad i could be of some help